# How to add/remove lines from the hosts file

Tags: powershell, hosts-file

I'd like to add and remove hosts file entries at a regular interval. I believe the easiest way to do this is powershell and task scheduler.

So how do you add/remove hosts file entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote up a few [powershell scripts that take](https://github.com/ianklatzco/powershell-hosts-editor) care of this. Just plop them into task scheduler at whatever interval you'd like.

Don't forget to [change powershell execution policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) to make sure the script runs.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a module a while back that provides a bunch of Cmdlets for managing the hosts file. It also supports tab completion of the hosts, which is handy.

The [source is on GitHub](https://github.com/richardszalay/pshosts) and it can be installed using PsGet:

```powershell
install-module PsHosts
```

You can then use it using the verbs:

```powershell
# Add a new entry
Add-HostEntry mysite.local 127.0.0.1

# Hit enter for all matching, hit tab to complete
Get-HostEntry mysite*

# Change existing
Set-HostEntry mysite.local 127.0.0.1

# Remove entry
Remove-HostEntry something.local

# Comments out an entry
Disable-HostEntry something.local
```

And because its all pipelined, it's pretty flexible:

```powershell
# Remove all disabled/commented *.local entries
Get-HostEntry *.local | ?{-not $_.Enabled} | Remove-HostEntry
```

If you spend more time in the IIS GUI than Powershell, I also made an IIS extension a few years back (they share code and unit tests) that has some additional site-specific features. [It's available on Codeplex](http://iishosts.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Nice module, how would one Toggle (Enabled/Disabled) an entry ?